# How can I load a java api of a C++ library in tomcat 7 (linux)?

Tags: java, c++, linux, tomcat, java-native-interface

I am trying to load to Tomcat 7 in linux a java api of a C++ library ([freeling](http://nlp.lsi.upc.edu/freeling/)). After reading several manuals about how to load a jni library (using LD_LIBRARY_PATH, Wl, rpath in the compilation, ldconfig...) I can't load the library.

I have to say that firstly I wrote a java standalone application and the library is loaded correctly. The problem appears when I transform the standalone application in a axis2 web service. I have followed the [pojo axis2 approach](http://axis.apache.org/axis2/java/core/docs/pojoguide.html) to build the service, and them I have embebed axis2 in tomcat. The error appears when I try to run the service. Also, I have to say that the system.loadlibrary works, and the error is returned when the first method of the library is called.

The error that I get when I call the web application is the following:

```
[ERROR] edu.upc.freeling.freelingJNI.Util_initLocale(Ljava/lang/String;)V
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at org.apache.axis2.rpc.receivers.RPCUtil.invokeServiceClass(RPCUtil.java:212)
        at org.apache.axis2.rpc.receivers.RPCMessageReceiver.invokeBusinessLogic(RPCMessageReceiver.java:117)
        at org.apache.axis2.receivers.AbstractInOutMessageReceiver.invokeBusinessLogic(AbstractInOutMessageReceiver.java:40)
        at org.apache.axis2.receivers.AbstractMessageReceiver.receive(AbstractMessageReceiver.java:114)
        at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.receive(AxisEngine.java:181)
        at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.HTTPTransportUtils.processHTTPPostRequest(HTTPTransportUtils.java:172)
        at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.AxisServlet.doPost(AxisServlet.java:146)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:647)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1023)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:310)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: edu.upc.freeling.freelingJNI.Util_initLocale(Ljava/lang/String;)V
        at edu.upc.freeling.freelingJNI.Util_initLocale(Native Method)
        at edu.upc.freeling.Util.initLocale(Util.java:39)
        at es.ujaen.metaphor.FreelingNLP.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at es.ujaen.metaphor.FigurativeLanguageWS.identifyFigurativeLanguageLemma(Unknown Source)
        at es.ujaen.metaphor.TestMetaphor.main(Unknown Source)
        ... 29 more
```

Thanks

Comment: Did you call `System.load("<path_to_freeling_so>")`?

Comment: I use System.loadlibray("freeling_javaAPI")

Comment: And that call throws no errors?

Comment: The System.loadlibrary function works. The problem is when I call to the first method of the library Util.initLocale("default"); I get a java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: edu.upc.freeling.freelingJNI.Util_initLocale(Ljava/lang/String;)V exception

Comment: That means that the native function was not found in any library that was loaded.  To eliminate the complexity of loading a library under Tomcat, please try a simple, standalone Java app that loads the library and calls that function.  If that doesn't work, then it sounds like there is something wrong with your jni library compilation.

Comment: That was my first step. Firstly I develop a java standalone application. The application works very well. Then, I built a pojo axis2 web service embebed in Tomcat 7. It is like tomcat doesn't find the funtion implementation. It's a bit frustrating because I have followed all the tutorials that I found on the Internet.

Comment: Yep. Sounds like the loadLibrary isn't being called within Tomcat. Update your question to include where you doing that.

Comment: Updated, and thanks for your responses